# visibility of 2 buttons with similar style WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I use a custom style WPF button with following style [ Purpose is button content (a star image ) is visible on mouseover only)

```
   <Style x:Key="ViewBookmarkRemoveButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverAnimation" >
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOutAnimation">
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image  Source="images\star_inactive.png" Margin="15" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="Transparent" >
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverAnimation}" />
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOutAnimation}" />
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

And in page xaml i used 2 instances of the button like this

```
 <StackPanel>

                <Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ViewBookmarkAddButtonStyle}"
                                   Name="btnLeft" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"                                  
                               ></Button>

                <Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ViewBookmarkAddButtonStyle}"
                                    Name="btnRight" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"                                        
                                    ></Button>
            </StackPanel>
```

But at run time only one button is visible. 
Is any such constarints exists or not? Or do i need to create a duplicate copy of one more style to make the second button also follow the same style?

Comment: You could set the visibility of let's say `btnRight` based on visibility of `btnLeft` using `Style`. Just another way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **x:Shared="False"** to style

---

**X:shared** : When set to false, modifies WPF resource-retrieval behavior so that requests for the attributed resource create a new instance for each request instead of sharing the same instance for all requests.

```
  <Style x:Key="ViewBookmarkRemoveButtonStyle" x:Shared="False"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        ....

  </Style>
```

Visit this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx) for x:Shared

**Another approach** : adding image in ContentPresenter.Content

```
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" >
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                <Image Source="login.jpg" Margin="2"/>
                            </ContentPresenter.Content>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear, so please forgive me if I have misunderstood it. I am addressing this part of your question:

> Or do i need to create a duplicate copy of one more style to make the second button also follow the same style?

In WPF, you can create a 'duplicate' `Style` using the [`Style.BasedOn` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
<Style x:Key="AlternativeButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ViewBookmarkAddButtonStyle}">
    <!-- Declare your different properties or Triggers here -->
</Style>
```

...

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ViewBookmarkAddButtonStyle}" Name="btnLeft"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource AlternativeButtonStyle}" Name="btnRight" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Its a useful info for me as well. But my question is related to another